# woocommerce_add_cart_item_data filter and add to cart not working - woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-plugin-creation

I add two filter to add extra information in cart items with filters. When click add to cart button, product not added in cart and Not showing any errors.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', array($this, 'addCartItemData'), 10, 3);
    add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', array($this, 'addItemData'), 10, 2); 

 public function addCartItemData($cart_item, $product_id, $variation_id)
    {

        global $woocommerce;

        $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id; 

        $eventtype=get_post_meta($product_id, "WooCommerceEventsType", true);

        print_r($eventtype); exit;

        if($eventtype == 'sequential'){

        if(isset($_POST['fooevent_class_date']) && !empty($_POST['fooevent_class_date'])) { $cart_item['fooevent_class_date'] = $_POST['fooevent_class_date']; }

        if(isset($_POST['fooevent_class_timing']) && !empty($_POST['fooevent_class_timing'])) { $cart_item['fooevent_class_timing'] = $_POST['fooevent_class_timing']; }
 

        }  

        return $cart_item;
    }


    /**
     * Add item data.
     */
    public function addItemData($item_data, $cart_item)
    {
        $product_id = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];

        $eventtype=get_post_meta($product_id, "WooCommerceEventsType", true);

          if($eventtype == 'sequential'){

        $class_date = $cart_item['fooevent_class_date'];

        $class_timing = $cart_item['fooevent_class_timing'];  
       
        $item_data['fooevent_class_date'] = array('key' => __('Class Date','fooevents-multiday-events'),'value' => $class_date);

        $item_data['fooevent_class_timing'] = array('key' => __('Class Timing','fooevents-multiday-events'),'value' => $class_timing);
        

        }  

        return $item_data;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

A filter should be passed a callback. Maybe try this

```
add_filter('woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'addCartItemData', 10, 3);
function addCartItemData($cart_item, $product_id, $variation_id) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_id = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $product_id;
    $eventtype = get_post_meta($product_id, "WooCommerceEventsType", true);

    print_r($eventtype);
    exit;

    if ($eventtype == 'sequential') {

        if (isset($_POST['fooevent_class_date']) && !empty($_POST['fooevent_class_date'])) {
            $cart_item['fooevent_class_date'] = $_POST['fooevent_class_date'];
        }

        if (isset($_POST['fooevent_class_timing']) && !empty($_POST['fooevent_class_timing'])) {
            $cart_item['fooevent_class_timing'] = $_POST['fooevent_class_timing'];
        }
    }
    return $cart_item;
}

// Add item data
add_filter('woocommerce_get_item_data', 'addItemData', 10, 2);
function addItemData($item_data, $cart_item) {
    $product_id = $cart_item['variation_id'] > 0 ? $cart_item['variation_id'] : $cart_item['product_id'];
    $eventtype = get_post_meta($product_id, "WooCommerceEventsType", true);

    if ($eventtype == 'sequential') {

        $class_date = $cart_item['fooevent_class_date'];
        $class_timing = $cart_item['fooevent_class_timing'];
        $item_data['fooevent_class_date'] = array('key' => __('Class Date', 'fooevents-multiday-events'), 'value' => $class_date);
        $item_data['fooevent_class_timing'] = array('key' => __('Class Timing', 'fooevents-multiday-events'), 'value' => $class_timing);
    }
    return $item_data;
}
```